# Uwsgi with miniconda2 env gives ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi, anaconda, conda

I have a flask service that is running in a miniconda2 environment. I installed uwsgi system wide with

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

Now when I try to launch my service using uwsgi.

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5000 --protocol=http --home /home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv -w wsgi.py
```

It gives me the folowing error.

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wait_prediction_api import app
  File "./wait_prediction_api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,abort,make_response
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import json
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 25, in <module>
    from itsdangerous import json as _json
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 14, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wait_prediction_api import app
  File "./wait_prediction_api.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,abort,make_response
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .app import Flask, Request, Response
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import json
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 25, in <module>
    from itsdangerous import json as _json
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 14, in <module>
    import hmac
  File "/home/ankit/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
    from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `-w wsgi:<app>`, with `<app>` being the name of the Flask application in your wsgi.py file.

Or use the more explicit

```
--wsgi-file wsgi.py --callable app
```